# Class Not Found Error in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys I'm trying to learn PHP frameworks as well as OOP and I'm using Laravel 5.1 LTS.

I have the following code in my `AuthController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Verification;
use Mail;
use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    private $redirectTo = '/home';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data){
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        // generate our UUID confirmation_code
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*15000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8)
        .substr($charid, 8, 4)
        .substr($charid,12, 4)
        .substr($charid,16, 4)
        .substr($charid,20,12);

        $data['confirmation_code'] = $uuid;

        // pass everything to the model here 
        $setVerification = new Verification();
        $setVerification->setVerificationCode($data['email'], $data['confirmation_code']);

        // send email for confirmation
        Mail::send('email.test', $data, function ($m) use ($data){
            $m->from('test@test.com', 'Your Application');
            $m->to($data['email'])->subject('Thanks for register! Dont forget to confirm your email address');
        });

        return $user;

    }

}
```

my error message `Class 'Models\Verification' not found` is coming from this piece of code here

```
// pass everything to the model here 
$setVerification = new Verification();
$setVerification->setVerificationCode($data['email'], $data['confirmation_code']);
```

which looks right to my beginner's eyes, but it's clearly wrong.

Here is my `Verification` class that has the `setVerificationCode method`

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Verification {

    /**
     * This method will update the confirmation_code column with the UUID
     * return boolean
     **/
    protected function setVerificationCode($email, $uuid) { 
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->uuid = $uuid;

        // check to see if $email & $uuid is set    
        if (isset($email) && isset($uuid)) {
            DB::table('users')
                    ->where('email', $email)
                    ->update(['confirmation_code' => $uuid]);

            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method will validate if the UUID sent in the email matches with the one stored in the DB
     * return boolean
     **/
    protected function verifyConfirmationCode() {

    }


}
```

Comment: This code does not seem fitting of a controller.  The problem, as answered by Haseena, is the namespace of Verification is App/Http/Controllers not App.  However, that namespace/location is likely not correct.

Comment: @Devon im really new to all of this and namespace is really confusing......

Answer (score 6):

Please give the following in AuthController

> use App\Http\Controllers\Verification;

instead of

> use App\Verification;

If we give **use App\Verification** , it will check if there is any model named Verification.

Comment: okay now im getting `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\User' not found
`

Comment: User is a model right.? then refer it as  use App\User;

Comment: my `Verification` class is my model file and it already includes `App\User`

Comment: While I am checking the code, u r using User model in AuthController only. then refer User model there only

Comment: $user = App\User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

Comment: Got it ? or Still have the same issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106966/discussion-between-hello-world-and-haseena-p-a).

Answer (score 1):

its seems that, you are missing something, which, Extend your `Model` with `eloquent model`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Verification extends Model
{
```

and the rest is seems fine.

also share your verification model code

---

**Updated**

---

instead of your this line

```
use App\Verification;
```

do this

```
use App\Models\Verification;
```

as you created custom directory for your `Models` then its better to auto load it in your `composer.json` file. add this line `"app/Models"` in your `"autoload"` section. follow this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"

    ],
```

and after that, run this command in your project repo `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: your error saying that, you have created `Model` directory under `App` directory, am I right >

Comment: Yes i have `App > Model > Verification.php`

Comment: still getting errors `Class 'App\Models\Verification' not found` why is this so hard..... i added `use App\Models\Verification;` in my `AuthController`

Comment: run this command in your project repo `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: can you show me screen shot of your `App` directory and onething more, did your extend your verification model with eloquent model. like this `class Verification extends Model{`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106970/discussion-between-hello-world-and-qazi).